# Iterative input fields sharing same onChange() function not giving input field specific event.target.values

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic select button based on the inputs from the iterative input fields I created. These input fields share the same `onChange()` function.

```
for (let i = 0; i < selectCount; i++) {
        widgetArr.push(
          <>
              <input key={i} id={`${i}`} onChange={(e) => {
                  handleInputValueChange(e, i)
              }} placeholder="options"/>
          </>
        )
    }
```

This is the `onChange()` function:

```
    const [optionArr, setOptionArr] = useState([])

    const handleInputValueChange = (event) => {
          
            setOptionArr([...optionArr, event.target.value])
        }
```

This how it used:

```
    const [selectCount, setSelectCount] = useState(0)
    <div>
              <label>Enter the number of options:</label>
              <Input onChange={(event: { target: { value: React.SetStateAction<number> } }) => {
                  setSelectCount(event.target.value)
              }} placeholder="number of options"/>
              <label>Enter the options:</label>
              <>
                  {widgetArr.map(obj => (
                    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
                    <div>
                        {obj}
                    </div>
                  ))}
              </>
          </div>
```

Based on the input number for `selectCount`, input fields were been populated. When I type any word on these input fields, those words were being save as bunch of letters based on the onChange() function on the relevant input field. What i need is to take all the letters i enter into a relevant input field as a whole text and save it as a option for select.

*PS: I also tried using a id in the input field. But it didn't work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

widgetArr should also be in a state variable using useState as current widgetArr doesn't rerender the component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-stonebraker-8knn9c?file=/src/App.js

for reference check out the link

Comment: still it doesn't push all the values into the `optionArr`.  It is always replacing the current value with last value pushed. also `selectCount` is also not updating.

Comment: can you check now with above url

Comment: now the `selectCount` is working fine but still `optionArr` is still giving only the last entered value.